# Codeigniter submit form written in plain HTML

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I'm playing for about 2 days now and can't make this out. I'm working in `codeigniter 2.1.0.` and I want to submit a form that is written in HTML. I don't want to use the CI form helper.

The reason is because I'm dynamically with JavaScript adding things in the form. When a user clicks an item then it's added to the form. Now when the user clicks the submit button all the items I added should be sent in a POST request, but my POST is totally empty.

Now I noticed that the POST only gets sent when I use `form_input()` from the CI form_helper.
Is it possible to just submit a normal plain HTML form without using the form helper?

Comment: Of course it is, and the form_input() just writes the html for you, nothing magical behind. Could you post the code you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to just submit a normal plain HTML form without using the form helper?

Yes. The actual submit is totally independent to CI, just ensure you use the correct action URI of the form so that the correct controller action is called by the form submit post (I assume your form method is post) request.

You do not need to use the CI form_helper for the submit button. If you mock a form with these you will see that those just generate plain HTML and do nothing magically.

Comment: omg, such noobish mistake of mine. I forgot to put the name attribute for the tags. But now I noticed that the things I add with my javascript don't get sent in the request. Any ideas why?

Comment: Ensure you place the dynamic form elements inside that form tag. As long as it is inside the form, it will be submitted. The browser does not care where the form is generated: server or client side - both is valid, even both at once.

Comment: They are being inserted in the form. I'm looking in firebug now and see that the tags arent closed although i closed them in the javascript. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Yes that can result in such problems. Take care to create valid HTML. Validate the page and with javascript manipulate the DOM, that is more save than inserting HTML strings.

Comment: In the end that's not the problem :). Looks like you cant put inputs that are type='image', they don't get sent. I tried changing it to type='text' and it gets sent. Now the only idea is that i set in the form normal images and have a hidden input where i will put the values i need. Maybe you know why input types image aren't being sent?

Comment: Yes input with type="image" need to be clicked to get send. Lol, check a HTML reference for the tags you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input ;)

Comment: I'm new to php and codeigniter too can anyone help me with some examples or tutorials for this form submit.

Comment: what about `action`. i just wrote   `action="<?php site_url ("controllerClassName/methodName")?>"` but i am getting in my table NULL values. what could be wrong.?